# Is DB::raw in insert method vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-injection, query-builder

I have a simplified code like this in Laravel:

```
$uid = $request->input('uid');
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'uid' => DB::raw("CONV('$uid', 16, 10)"),
    'created_at' =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
]);
```

Is my code vulnerable to SQL Injection attack? And Why? If so, how can I prevent it?

Comment: You're doing an injection with `$uid`, so yes, you've created an injection vulnerability.

Comment: Tip: Do the conversion in PHP, then pass in the plain old parameter without `DB::raw`.

Comment: @tadman I had to deal with unsigned 64 bit integer that's why I preferred the mysql way to convert the hex value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's vulnerable to SQL Injection since the raw content of `$uid` will be injected to your sql query.

Although `DB::raw()` accepts prepared parameters, it cannot be used inside the insert method correctly.

To do that, you will need to write the insert query manually:

```
$uid = $request->input('uid');

DB::statement('INSERT INTO users (uid, created_at) VALUES (CONV(?, 16, 10), ?)', [
    $uid,
    date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, It gives me this error: `Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ':uid' (SQL: insert into 'users' ('uid', 'created_at') values (CONV(':uid', 16, 10), 2020-04-08 20:39:33)) in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669`

Comment: Parameters cannot go inside SQL quotes. You must use `"CONV(:uid, 16, 10)"`.

Comment: @BillKarwin Sadly it still gives me error: `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: insert into users (uid, created_at) values (CONV(:uid, 16, 10), 2020-04-08 20:59:41))`. It looks like it doesn't pass `uid` value to raw query at all!

Comment: It seems Laravel doesn't support this: https://laravel.io/forum/12-10-2014-mysql-functions-in-insert-query-using-query-builder

Comment: Please try the updated code. Not sure, I'm writing from mobile right now. If don't work, tomorrow I update my answer with correct code. Sorry.

Comment: @EliasSoares Unfortunately it's not working again: `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: insert into users (uid, created_at) values (CONV(2020-04-08 21:14:46, 16, 10), ?))`

Comment: Yes. I guess it's the only solution as Laravel doesn't support `DB:raw` in `insert` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, copying a request input directly into your raw SQL query is an example of an SQL injection vulnerability.

I suggest this alternative:

```
$uid = base_convert($request->input('uid'), 16, 10);
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'uid' => $uid,
    'created_at' =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
]);
```

See [base_convert()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php).

---

Comment: This is not my answer actually. As PHP cannot handle unsigned big integer, I cannot convert `ffffffffffffffff` to decimal which is `18446744073709551615` of course I can use custom functions but it's not related to vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: MySQL's CONV() function is also limited to 64-bits. If you need larger numbers, use PHP's `base_convert()`. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks but `base_convert()` returns `18446744073709552046` for `ffffffffffffffff` which is incorrect. The correct value is `18446744073709551615`